# table and arrow in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, arrows

I only can create a table like:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{DTE to DEC} \\ 
\hline 
DTE device (Computer) & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{DB9} & Connection & DTE device (Computer) & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{DCE device (Modem)} \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Pin DB9 R232 Signal name} & Signal Direction & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Pin DB9 R232 Signal name} \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

But how to design and create a table like follow picture with color arrow?

[image]

Comment: Please, make your code sniped as complete, minimal document, which can be compiled. I'm afraid that table is to wide to fit text width in beamer or in this case it will have very small fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Modem cable - Straight Cable DB9 to DB9}
\framesubtitle{DTRE to DCE}

\centering
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{|c|l|c| c |c|l|c|}
\mc{}   &   \mc{DTE device (Computer)}  &   \mc{DB9}    
    &   \mc{Connection}
        &   \mc{}   &   \mc{DCE device (Modem)}  &   \mc{DB9}                \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Pin DB9 R232 Signal name} 
    &    Direction  
        &   \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Pin DB9 R232 Signal name}                  \\
    \hline
\#1     &   Carrier Detector (DCD)  &   CD  
    &   \tikz[baseline=-2pt]\draw[ultra thick,blue, <-] (0,0) -- (0.9,0);
        &   \#1 &   Carrier Detector (DCD)  &   CD                          \\
    \hline
\#2     &   Receive Data (Rx)       &   RD
    &   \tikz[baseline=-2pt]\draw[ultra thick,green, <-] (0,0) -- (0.9,0);
        &   \#2 &   Receive Data (Rx)       &   RD                          \\
    \hline
\#3     &   Transmith Data (Rx)     &   RD
    &   \tikz[baseline=-2pt]\draw[ultra thick,red, ->] (0,0) -- (0.9,0);
        &   \#3 &   Transmith Data (Rx)     &   RD                          \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

On the showed way you can write missing rows of table.